# Error en la función, captura() takes 1 posisional arguemnt but 3 were given

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

El objetivo del código es leer el valor(high - low) de GPIO DTA YB, únicamente cuando detecte la interrupción (falling) en CLK. Ese cambio debe almacenarlo en un archivo de texto previamente creado, en orden para poder gratificarlo después.

En el siguiente script intente realizar esos objetivos, pero me quede atascado en la función que me arroja el siguiente error:

> captura() takes 1  posisional arguement but 3 were given

Intenté probar con variables globales, pero no puedo solucionarlo:

```py
def captura (self)
```

Por cierto, lo que debe hacer es tomar el dato del estado de YB y DTA, cambiarlo de valor según corresponda (high - low) en la cadena y pasar al siguiente. Para incluír una especie de contador que debería cumplir la parte de recorrer la cadena.

```py
import pigpio, numpy as np

CLKpin=21
DTApin=20
YBpin=16

    
pi = pigpio.pi()

pi.set_mode(CLKpin, pigpio.INPUT)
pi.set_mode(DTApin, pigpio.INPUT)
pi.set_mode(YBpin, pigpio.INPUT)


archivo = open("datos" + ".txt", "a")



#CLK = np.zeros(8500, dtype= int)
DTA=np.zeros(8500, dtype= int)
YB=np.zeros(8500, dtype= int)


ctr=0

def captura (self):
    
    global DTA
    global YB
    global ctr
    ctr = ctr+1
    
    self.DTA[ctr]= pi.read(DTApin)
    self.YB[ctr]=pi.read(YBpin)
    
    
try:

    cb1 = pi.callback(CLKpin, pigpio.FALLING_EDGE, captura)

except:

    archivo.write(salida)
```

Comment: La documentación: https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#:~:text=CE)%0A%0Api.stop()-,callback,-(user_gpio%2C (o lo que yo creo que es la documentación) dice que el callback debe aceptar tres argumentos. La solución sería hacer que la función acepte los argumentos (aunque al final no los uses).

Comment: parece que si brooo

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con la documentación:

La función de callback recibe tres parámetros: el GPIO, el nivel y el tick.

```
Parameter   Value    Meaning

GPIO        0-31     The GPIO which has changed state

level       0-2      0 = change to low (a falling edge)
                     1 = change to high (a rising edge)
                     2 = no level change (a watchdog timeout)

tick        32 bit   The number of microseconds since boot
                     WARNING: this wraps around from
                     4294967295 to 0 roughly every 72 minutes
```

Y se usan como en este ejemplo:

```
def cbf(gpio, level, tick):
   print(gpio, level, tick)

cb1 = pi.callback(22, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, cbf)
```

Por lo tanto, la solución es que declares `captura` con los parámetros correctos:

```
def captura (gpio, level, tick):
```

Comment: buena @Candid Moe